# Why can't an AngularJS Promise retrieve headers from a WEB API Response?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Can someone explain to me if it is possible to get a header from a Web API response within an AngularJS Promise?

I am making the following call:

```
return $http({
        url: "http://localhost:19260/api/Authentication/Login/{credentials}",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            var jwt= response.headers('A‌​uthorization'); //Always null!!!!
            auth = true;
        }
        else {
            auth = false; 
        }
    }, function (response) {
        auth = false; 
    });
```

Every time I try to read my header via "response.headers(...)" the value is null. Why is this? I can see the header and its value present when I look at the response in Fiddler. Why can't AngularJS see it?

Is this CORS issue? Both client/server are running on the localhost, but with different ports. If so, what is wrong with my CORS implementation? (C#)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Authentication/Login/{credentials}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]CredentialContainer credentials)
    {
          var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
          var jwt = GetJwtToken(credentials);            
          response.Headers.Add("Authorization", jwt);
          response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
          return response;
    }
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27623389/215552. It's not a duplicate, but provides good advice on using CORS in Web API.

Comment: enableCors() in global.asax too?

Comment: @naveen Do you mean in the WebApiConfig.cs?

Comment: @mike I tried both suggestions there, same result.

Comment: yes. that is called in `Global.asax` Also when you inspect the call, is it `POST` or  `OPTIONS` in console?

Comment: @naveen Can you give me an example of what I should be doing in the Global.asax.cs? Also, I am using POST. Do I need to make an OPTIONS call somewhere in my Angular controller?

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` installed?

Comment: @naveen yep, I installed it through Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Two points you might not consider in your web api service and webserver configurations:

**First:**
Since non-default headers value are not showing to client-side (i.e Authorization and any other custom header) untill you expose them by setting some configuration in webserver(IIS Web.config). You can expose them in `Web.config` like here:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

If you're gana set these configurations for all api, This is the best way and there is no need to add `enable-cors` attribute at top of each method. Also setting these configurations in web.config is much more easier and works beter (As my experiences).

**Second:**
You're not getting the authorization value in header correctly in ajax request.
try this code instead:

```
return $http({
        url: "http://localhost:19260/api/Authentication/Login/{credentials}",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            //Try this one
            var jwt= headers('A‌​uthorization');
            auth = true;
        }
        else {
            auth = false; 
        }
    }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        auth = false; 
    });
```

Hope this can help you Bro. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately, this does not work. My response object is now an empty string "", and the headers object still does not have my value in it.

Comment: You're welcome Bro, No problem. You can check the response in google chrome developer options (Ctrl + Shift + I), then go to network tab. Now trigger your desired request to the server, After the response successfully recieved you can have all the information about the request and response incluing headers, etc. If your response content was null again you must debug your server-side code again but if not try to refactor the client-side request snippet code. Inform me again if you wont get your result. GL